# Infinity In Math - The Nick Lim Proposal

Tags: infinity

So infinity is clearly a very strange, concept.

So I have the following proposal (the nick lim proposal) which can not be solved ( at least to my current knowledge, hopefully you can shed some light ).

For the following scenarios since I do not have an infinity character on my keyboard, replace x with the infinity symbol.

What is x/x?

Well we know 2x = x

So we could rewrite x/x = 2x/x

Well 2x/x

Well in that scenario x/x = x

But

lets flip that around

2x = x so x/x = x/2x

In this scenario x/x = 1/2 //Think of limits imagine y/2y as y approaches infinity it's 1/2.

So it seems x/x = "1/k where k is all positive integers" or "just x"

Edit: 1.1x = x and 1.5x = x and .1x = x

So x/x = "1/k where k is all positive real numbers" or "just x"

What do you think?

Comment: $\infty/\infty$ (obtained by writing `$\infty / \infty$`) is what is known as an indeterminate form, much like $0/0$. You can make it become whatever you wish, but in specific settings, it is very possible that it has a specific value.

Comment: But in my explanation isn't that not true? It can only be a certain number of values that are determinate?

Comment: Also down voting this question is ridiculous, if you disagree you can simply post or comment.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to treat $\infty$ as if it were an ordinary number, which it is not. Pushing symbols around without regard to their meaning generally results in nonsense. "Garbage in, garbage out."

Comment: And I agree with your comment about downvoting, by the way. +1 for that.

Comment: Hmm, I appreciate your rationale, I will look into infinity more. It is definitely a very strange concept.

Comment: At this time it seems there is no real answer to x/x, but I will continue to work on it.

Comment: There's no math in your question, I'm afraid. Jotting down symbols and saying something like “we know $2\infty=\infty$” is not doing mathematics.  To a statement such as “$\infty/\infty=1/k$ where $k$ is all positive numbers“ I cannot attribute any sensible meaning. Are you really surprised about two downvotes? I'm surprised there aren't more, to be honest. No, I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 3):

What would you think of the reasonning " $0 \times 1 = 0 \times 2$ so $1 = 2$" ?
Both products $= 0$, so you can't simplify.

Similarily $\infty \times 1 = \infty \times 2$ cannot implies 1 = 2 for the same reason: both products are infinity, so you can't simplify.

Answer (score 0):

$\infty$ is the limit of t at infinity.
$\infty$ is also the limit of 2t at infinity.

When you write $\frac \infty \infty$, there is no reason that both $\infty$ are set to the same sequence, each could freely map to any sequence going to infinity. That's why the result is indeterminated, and that's why your reasonning is flawed.

Comment: but in the form 2t/t as t approaches infinity the limit would be two because the top grows twice as quick as the bottom considering you can never GET to infinity correct?

Comment: yes  the form 2t/t as t approaches infinity the limit would be two (ideed it's 2 at any time) . Just, it is totally wrong to pretend that writting $\frac {2\infty} \infty$ is equivalent to writting this limit (I explained why many times above).

Comment: 2infinity/1infinity, lets cancel the infinities that equals 2/1

Comment: No. not in maths, not in science. We spent hour here to explain you why. But if you don't accept any math/science argument, it'd your freedom to decided to create a brand new different mathematics elsewhere that in a math forum.